# Showing one child page in main navigation

Tags: structure

Is it possible to show one child page as a main navigation item? I tried the include parameter but it's not quite right.

> The parameter "include=" can be used to selectively show specific pages from the same level. http://buildwithstructure.com/tags/navigation/

It needs to be a child page but also be a main navigation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution from their docs:
[**Duplicate Pages In Navigation**](http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/duplicate_pages_in_navigation/).

> You can have pages live in more than one place in your navigation by
>   creating a redirect to one “official” place the page lives.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Although some of the syntax is out of date I found this explanation easier to understand than the Structure docs http://mikeheavers.com/main/code-item/redirects_in_structure_for_expression_engine

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that this is not possible using Structure tags. The navigation works off the hierarchy.

Best option is to use jQuery to manually insert the navigation item. Here's a rough how-to:

Set your `{exp:structure:nav}` tag to use `add_unique_ids="yes"`. Let's say this outputs:

```
<ul>
    <li id="link1"></li>
    <li id="link2"></li>
    <li id="link3"></li>
</ul>
```

Then use jQuery to insert your new nav link where appropriate. Something like this:

```
$('#link1').after('<li id="inserted"></li>');
```

This will get you this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="link1"></li>
<li id="inserted"></li>
    <li id="link2"></li>
    <li id="link3"></li>
</ul>
```

There may be a jump in the nav list as the item is inserted so I'd suggest hiding the UL with CSS and then showing it after the insert with JS... something like:

```
ul {
    display: none;
}

$('ul').show();
```

You'll need to adjust the selectors to work with your code.

Comment: Thanks. I did initially consider this but it's not maintainable and also not a good idea having the clients navigation hidden by default in case JS fails.